# All the sites currently have no questions

Tags: bug, questions, stack-exchange

I checked unix.stackexchange.com, cs.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, math.stackechange.com, tex.stackexchange.com and superuser.com. No questions at all, but some of the sites did ask me to review new posts.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro]

Comment: This site works...

Comment: I just submitted [Why are there 0 questions?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/6335). SO and MSO don't seem to be affected.

Comment: Closed and reopened Firefox, still no questions.

Comment: Now stackoverflow.com is back, the rest stays questionless.

Comment: My mistake, _questions_ appear, no _unanswered_ questions. But not on all sites, only on superuser.com it seems.

Comment: [Status repro](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Gd4.png).

Comment: More info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166885/sites-tags-are-intermittently-devoid-of-questions

Comment: Re: "This site works" I know, no repro on [su] and [math.se] also

Comment: Infinite loop of duplication...